# Sending data through Components

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-router

I am having this problem which I can not solve. So basically I have 2 components here Component A and Component G I have more of them but they are pretty much the same(concept is the same). I have a Link in Component G, A which when I click it, it brings me to the Payment Component. Tt now renders the (ImageA, ClassA and PriceA) its hard coded. Anyway what I am trying to achieve is that when I click for example on the Component G it renders only that (imageG, classG and priceG), so I would need it to filter it somehow or split the data somehow in the json file I imagine, but I dont know how to do it. I hope one of you fellow comrades will help me.

```
Payment Component

const Payment = ({
  history,
  location: { state },
  match: {
    params: { dataId }
  }
}) => {
  if (!state?.postData) {
    history.goBack();
  }

  const { postData } = state;

  return (
    <div className="ml-20">
      <img
        alt=""
        className="w:2/4 object-contain "
        src={postData.imageG}     
        />
      <h2
        className=" ml-24 mlg:ml-6 mlg:mt-2 mlg:static text-5xl mlg:text-2xl text-blue-400 absolute top- 
        48"  >
        {postData.classG}
      </h2>
      <h3
        className="text-lg  mlg:mb-2 mlg:ml-6  mlg:mt-2 mlg:static font-bold text-green-800 
                 font-mono ml-24 top-64  absolute"
      >
        {postData.priceG}
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Payment

A COMPONENT
import React from "react";
import data from "../data.json";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function A() {
  return (
    <div className='bg-black '>
{data.filter(d =>
  d.classA &&
  d.imageA &&
  d.priceA)
  .map((postData) => {
        return (
          <div className='bg-black'  key={postData.id} >
            <div className='bg-black '>            
              <img
                alt=""
                className="w-full object-contain "
                src={postData.imageA}
              ></img>
              <h1 className=" ml-24 mlg:ml-6 mlg:mt-2 mlg:static text-5xl mlg:text-2xl text-red-600 
                  absolute top-48">
                  {postData.classA}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="text-lg  mlg:mb-2 mlg:ml-6  mlg:mt-2 mlg:static font-bold text-yellow-600 
                  font-mono ml-24 top-64  absolute" >
                  {postData.priceA}
              </h1>
              <Link
                to={{pathname: `/payment/${postData.id}`,
                state: {
                  postData,
                },
              }}
                className="py-1 px-2  mlg:ml-6 mlg:mt-14 mlg:static text-black-600 h-8  ml-24  top-72 bg- 
                white w-32 text-center text-gray-red
                rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-600 absolute" 
              >
                Buy Now
              </Link>

             </div>
               </div>
                 </div>
                )
                 }
export default A

G Component
import React from "react";
import data from "../data.json";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function G() {
  return (
    <div className='bg-black '>
{data.filter(d =>
  d.classG &&
  d.imageG &&
  d.priceG)
  .map((postData) => {
        return (
          <div className='bg-black'  key={postData.id} >
            <div className='bg-black '>            
              <img
                alt=""
                className="w-full object-contain "
                src={postData.imageG}
              ></img>
              <h1 className=" ml-24 mlg:ml-6 mlg:mt-2 mlg:static text-5xl mlg:text-2xl text-red-600 
                  absolute top-48">
                  {postData.classG}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="text-lg  mlg:mb-2 mlg:ml-6  mlg:mt-2 mlg:static font-bold text-yellow-600 
                  font-mono ml-24 top-64  absolute" >
                  {postData.priceG}
              </h1>
              <Link
                to={{pathname: `/payment/${postData.id}`,
                state: {
                  postData,
                },
              }}
                className="py-1 px-2  mlg:ml-6 mlg:mt-14 mlg:static text-black-600 h-8  ml-24  top-72 bg- 
                white w-32 text-center text-gray-red
                rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-600 absolute" 
              >
                Buy Now
              </Link>

             </div>
               </div>
                 </div>
                )
                 }
export default G

Json file

[
   {
    "id":0,
    "classG":"G-Class",
    "imageG":"./ModImages/Gclass.jpg",
    "priceG":"Starting at $154,900",
     "newG":"A 12.3-inch digital gauge cluster is newly standard across the 
     board, as are heated front seats. Plus, the sedan can be had with a Night 
     package that adds black exterior trim.",
    "imageGIn":"./ModImages/GclassIn.jpg",
    "imageCOut":"./ModImages/GclassOut.jpg",
    "infoDesignC1":"How many technological breakthroughs can you fit into a C- 
    Class? With the advanced, powerful and sporty 2020 C 300 Wagon, plenty. From 
    its LED headlamps to its generous cargo hold, you'll find countless 
    refinements, and so many reasons it's a wagon like no other.",
    "infoDesignG" :"The acclaimed C-Class cabin is as functional as it is 
    beautiful. Abundant innovations harmonize with five options in hand-finished 
    wood trim. A 12.3-inch digital instrument cluster and 10.25-inch centre 
    screen are available.",
    "imageGIn1":"./ModImages/CclassIn1.jpg",
    "imageGOut1":"./ModImages/CclassOut1.jpg",
    "infoDesign2": "The Star on the outside is earned on the inside. The roomy, 
    refined cabin includes heated front seats and a driver-seat memory. Dual- 
    zone, double-filtered climate control. A panoramic sunroof. And options from 
    Burmester® surround sound to new Climate Comfort front seats.",
    "infoInov": "Available Apple CarPlay™ and Android Auto let you enjoy more 
    from your own smartphone. Another navigation option is COMAND, which brings 
    you voice control not only for navigation and audio, but also many cabin 
    features.",
    "imageInov1":"./ModImages/GclassInov1.jpg",
    "imageInov2":"./ModImages/GclassInov2.jpg",
    "infoInov1": "Available wireless charging lets you refuel your compatible 
     phone's battery as you drive. Easy-connect NFC pairing links your phone 
     every 
     time you get in. Apple CarPlay™ and Android Auto are available, too. And 
     four USB-C ports are standard.",
    "infoInov2": "DYNAMIC SELECT lets you fine-tune your A-Class with the tap of 
     a console button. Four modes vary shift points, throttle response, steering 
     feel and more: efficient ECO, everyday Comfort, sharpened Sport, and create- 
     your-own Individual.",
    "imageInov":"./ModImages/GclassInov.jpg",
    "imageInov4":"./ModImages/GclassInov4.jpg" ,
    "infoInov4G": "From the everyday to the unexpected, Mercedes me connect helps 
     ease your way. You can control vehicle features from your smartphone 
     (including Remote Start), set up a service appointment, and more. You can  
     also add In-car Wi-Fi for a low monthly rate. ",
    "infoInov5C":"Available driver assists help de-stress driving, changing lanes 
    with a tap of your finger, and knowing to slow for a tollboth or exit. A 
    network of sensors keeps a constant lookout for danger ahead, even if it's 
    coming from behind."
   },

   {
    "id":1,
    "classA":"A-Class",
    "imageA":"./ModImages/Aclass.jpg",
    "priceA":"Starting at $54,900",
    "newA":"In addition to a new 18-inch wheel design, the 2021 A-class gains 
    standard blind-spot monitoring and an optional gesture control feature for 
    the MBUX infotainment system.",
    "imageAIn":"./ModImages/AclassIn.jpg",
    "imageAOut":"./ModImages/AclassOut.jpg",
    "infoDesignA":"A is for attention-getting. The clean lines, LED lighting and 
    aggressive stance of the A-Class Sedan are designed to capture admiring eyes. 
    Its ultramodern cabin and premium appointments aim to captivate its driver 
    and passengers for years to come.",
    "infoDesignA1" :"With 100% LED lighting standard, inside and out, the A-Class 
    shines day or night, coming or going, and staying, too. Options include 
    MULTIBEAM LED headlamps and 64-colour ambient cabin lighting.",
    "imageAIn1":"./ModImages/AclassIn1.jpg",
    "imageAOut1":"./ModImages/AclassOut1.jpg",
    "infoDesignA2": "The Star on the outside is earned on the inside. The roomy, 
    refined cabin includes heated front seats and a driver-seat memory. Dual- 
    zone, double-filtered climate control. A panoramic sunroof. And options from 
    Burmester® surround sound to new Climate Comfort front seats.",
    "infoInov": "A is for advanced. With the Mercedes-Benz User Experience 
    (MBUX), the A-Class drives a new generation of user-friendly tech. Quite 
    possibly the most capable, natural and intuitive speech interface from any 
    automaker, it's easy to learn because it learns you.",
    "imageInov1":"./ModImages/AclassInov1.jpg",
    "imageInov2":"./ModImages/AclassInov2.jpg",
    "infoInov1": "Available wireless charging lets you refuel your compatible 
     phone's battery as you drive. Easy-connect NFC pairing links your phone 
     every time you get in. Apple CarPlay™ and Android Auto are available, too. 
     And four USB-C ports are standard. Disclaimer[6] Disclaimer",
    "infoInov2": "DYNAMIC SELECT lets you fine-tune your A-Class with the tap of 
    a console button. Four modes vary shift points, throttle response, steering 
    feel and more: efficient ECO, everyday Comfort, sharpened Sport, and create- 
     your-own Individual.",
    "imageInov3":"./ModImages/AclassInov3.jpg",
    "imageInov4":"./ModImages/AclassInov4.jpg" ,
    "infoInov4": "Get up close with the A-Class Sedan in this captivating ASMR audio experience. "
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm updating the answer based on the comments**

First thing, I would make sure my JSON properties are consistent across objects:

```
[
   {
    "id":0,
    "class":"G-Class",
    "image":"./ModImages/Gclass.jpg",
    "price":"Starting at $154,900",
    "new":"Mercedes-Benz introduces a mid-cycle update of the E-class lineup for 2021. The changes 
     apply",
    "infoInov": "....",
    "imageOut": "..."
   },

   {
    "id":1,
    "class":"A-Class",
    "image":"./ModImages/Aclass.jpg",
    "price":"Starting at $54,900",
    "new":"Mercedes-Benz introduces a mid-cycle update of the E-class lineup for 2021. The changes 
     apply",
    "infoInov": "....",
    "imageOut": "..."
   }
]
```

Since all the properties are consistent, the only way you can consistently tell them apart is by the `id` property. If `id === 0`, we know it's the G. `if === 1`, we know it's A, and so on.

This way, I can use only one component to render them both. If you want to apply different styles or render something if it's component G, you can do something like:

```
function AG() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-black">
      {data.map(product => (
         <div>
           <img src={product.image} />
           <h1>{product.class}</h1>
           <h1 className={product.id === 0 ? 'g-class' : ''}>{product.price}</h1>
           <Link to={`/payment/${product.id}` />
           {product.id === 0 && <div>This will only appear to G</div>}
         </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Notice above that I have some checks to apply styles or render something only if `product.id === 0`. This is one of the ways to reuse a component and apply little changes to it.

In the `<Link>` we are sending the user to `/payments` passing the productID in the path. So inside the `Payments` component, you would use this productID to filter the data from the JSON.

Now in the Payment component, you can just import the same JSON `data` and filter by the `id` we are passing in the URL path:

```
import data from "../data.json"

const Payment = () => {
  // get the id from the URL somehow, I suppose you are using react router
  // this is just an example
  const { idFromURL } = match.param

  const filteredProduct = data.filter(product => product.id === idFromURL)

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={filteredProduct.image} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now the `filteredProduct` variable has the data for either A or G, and you can use it to display the specific data you want, inside the Payment component.

Comment: I have updated the json file. Concept is the same in Components but data is not. Thats why I could not pull everything from json into the one Component, and styling is not the same as well.

Comment: I see. Having a JSON file with consistent keys would be a good practice in my point of view, so you could apply dynamic styles by referencing the `id` property. Like, if `id === 0`, apply some `className`. 

But since you might not be able to do this, you can import the `data` into your Payment component and filter the data by the `idFromURL`. Does it work for you?

Comment: So what Do I need to so. I dont understand you sorry

Comment: I will edit my answer with some steps I would take, just a moment =)

Comment: There you go, if you still have difficulties, you can create a small repo and share here, so we can iterate together

Comment: So can you  look  at this https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-buck-s1b96 btw i have more Components

Comment: You can take a look at this proof of concept I've made: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-forest-ugpl6

Hope it helps!

Comment: Have you seen my sandbox. In the first page/Home they are links which are leading to different pages/routes they all have different css, and all of them are sharing Link/Buy Now but when pressed they are supposed to bring you Payment page and on the Payment page and then display the specific (image, class and price) of that Component

Comment: Yess, I just made a fork and changed a little bit to make it work. I believe the sandbox I created is doing exactly what you are looking for, except there are no styles (because when I forked there were no css files) and is not showing images because there are no images in the sandbox. But the main goal is to click the "Buy now" button and be redirected to the /payment route, where I get the productID from the URL and display the information at the page

Comment: Gotta be honest it is not. In my sandbox on the main page they are links. When links is pressed  that takes you to the that Component/class and when the buy now is press that takes you to the payment page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226902/discussion-between-yaiks-and-tequila).